# How to optimize query with date calculation

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

This is my table structure (about 1 millions records):

[image: index table]

I need to select a few indices at certain dates, but only Year and Month are relevant:

```
SELECT `index_name`,`results` FROM `mst_ind` WHERE 
((`index_name`='MSCI EAFE Mid NR USD' AND MONTH(`date`) = 3 AND YEAR(`date`) = 2003) OR
(`index_name`='MSCI Morocco PR USD' AND MONTH(`date`) = 3 AND YEAR(`date`) = 2003))
AND `time_period`='M1'
```

It works fine, but the performance is horrible. I run the query through profiler, but it could not suggest any possible keys.

The primary key contains index_id, date and time_period.

How can I optimize/improve this query?

Thanks!

Update: the explain report:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are probably invalidating the use of an index as you are applying a transformation to fields that would be indexed by using functions such as `MONTH` and `YEAR`.
You could:

- write the `WHERE` clause differently such that it doesn't use the `MONTH` and `YEAR` functions, such as:

  `date` >= '2003-03-01' and `date` < '2003-04-01'

Edit: just realized you probably don't have any indexes on this table. Consider adding indexes to the `index_name`, `date` and `time_period` field.

Comment: MySQL unlike Oracle doesn't support function-based indices. Therefore rewriting `WHERE` condition so that it doesn't apply any functions to `date` column is the only option.

Comment: I do have two keys (index_id, date and time_period) and (index_name, date and time_period). It doesn't make any difference. What I've noticed that changing the query string from "`index_name`='MSCI EAFE Mid NR USD'..." to "`index_id`='FAWER45QS'" improves the performance from 1 sec to 0.045 sec. Still looking for some better suggestions.

Comment: Can you post an EXPLAIN of the query so we can see what indexes it has chosen to use

Comment: EXPLAIN report added.

Comment: From the explain it is not using any indexes at all. Neither index is going to be of any use for checking part of the date as it will have to perform a function on the date on each row to get the value (but using the suggestion by @Lock should solve this). I am surprised it has not used the 2nd index (index_name, date and time_period) but I would assume that the 2 values specified for the index_name field cover most of the rows, hence not useful.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion of removing the MONTH and YEAR functions? You will never get it to use your index unless you do this.